# Email: [Firebase] Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in X day(s)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I got an email that indicates I was developing in "test mode", but that it left my database completely open to the internet.  The default rules I initially accepted look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2019, 12, 14);
    }
  }
}
```

What needs to be done to satisfy the request of this email?

Comment: How to add rule to allow access if it's from localhost only ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The security rules shown here are a departure from the previous default rules that were much more permissive.  The idea with this rule:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2019, 12, 14);
}
```

Is that you get unrestricted access to your Firestore database up until the given date, in order to freely experiment with it for a month.  However, allowing unrestricted access is obviously a massive security hole in the long run.

The recommended course of action is to first **remove this rule entirely as it allows anyone to read and write anything in your database**.  Then, devise some proper rules that allow only access to collections and documents that your eventual users should be able to access.  A full discussion of that is off-topic for Stack Overflow (as we don't know your app's requirements), but here are some good places to start learning about security rules:

- [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview)
- [This video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLn8h1NyU_OV6dX8mBhH2s_L)

What you should be doing is calling out the access constraints for each collection and subcollection in your database.  Ideally, you should lock down unauthenticated write access to all collections, except where absolutely required.  In the best case, you're using Firebase Authentication to help control access to documents [only as required for authenticated users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Alternatively, if you're done working with the database (for the time being), you can block access to the database from web and mobile client entirely by using the following rule exclusively:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read, write: if false;
  }
}
```

With this rule, access from backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK or other Cloud SDKs will still be allowed.

Answer (score 23):

Or if you are like me, who's still in test mode? Just update the date

```
match /{document=**} {  
   // from previous date 2019, 12, 14 to new date 2020, 01, 4
   allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 01, 4); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you start a new project on firebase (or) setup a firestore database, firebase by default adds a set of rules for your database, which looks something like this.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(XXXX, XX, XX);
    }
  }
}
```

The "timestamp.date" dates to 1 month from when you start the project. More or less like a 30day free trial.
Upon bypassing this date, the database denies all the client requests.
So, the email is basically a reminder for you to change the security rules.
One simple way is to allow read/write requests only to authenticated users.

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, this is one of the ways to define the rules and need not exactly as shown, you could further make modifications as per your requirements.
For more information, you can have a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)

Answer (score 5):

When you create a firestore db, you get access for 30 days. Your rule looks like this. See date, allowing read/write for certain duration,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 8, 17);
    }
  }
}
```

The date part is important here. You can increase this date if you want to use it in Test mode for longer period.

```
request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 10, 30);
```

OR, it's better to set access to any authenticated user while you're developing your app, like

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Its good to be more specific always, especially when you are deploying in production. In that case your rule can be,

```
 match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
```

You can read more in detail in official documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics

Answer (score 0):

Firebase] Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in 2 day(s)

You chose to start developing in Test Mode, which leaves your Cloud Firestore database completely open to the Internet. Because your app is vulnerable to attackers, your Firestore security rules were configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days.
In 2 day(s), all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied. Before that time, please write strong security rules that allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data. Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24 hours those changes may not be accounted for.

If u receive this kind of email from the firebase then you have to go to the edit rules and then change the date  simply.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Firestore in Test Mode which provides a trail of 30 days.
After that if you want to use it for a longer duration, you need to update the rules in Firestore.

Your current rule would look like:

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if
           request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 1, 18);
     }
   }
 }
```

Now you need to update it !

Alternatively, You can increase this date if you want to use it in Test mode for longer period (it can be increased for 1 month from today).

OR, it's better to set access to any authenticated user while you're developing your app, like

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

OR If you are deploying in production. In that case your rule could be,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Just change your rule by any of the above 2 rules and you are all good to go.

Answer (score 0):

for firebase v9 you can just update the timeframe you want to use the test db with updating the rules shown in the screenshot below:

[image]