# Firebase - Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in 3 day(s)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firestore Google database just to play around and test some stuff.

My rules are configured to this right now, and to me this should allow us to continue reading and writing to the database but we are no longer able to because client access has expired. Does anyone have any insight as to what would work? I'm really just trying to play around and test some stuff, not necessarily looking for super great security right now.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "client access has expired"? That's not something that happens to Firebase clients.  What exactly are you observing?  Please edit the question to be specific. The rules you're showing here do not limit client access in any way.

Comment: @DougStevenson The default rules nowadays provide public access for 1 month and then expire. It seems like OP got a warning about that. Which you wrote about a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869759/email-firebase-client-access-to-your-cloud-firestore-database-expiring-in-x-d :)

Comment: @Kat `if true` is pretty much the opposite of "super great security", it makes it so that anyone can read/write all data in your database. If that is exactly what you want, then go for it. But since you say "right now", I'd consider instead extending the data range in the security rules. The date in `if request.time < timestamp.date(2019, 12, 14)` is actually pretty readable, so you can extend it to when you think you'll be done with development. That reduces the risk to at least a limited time frame.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Right, but the rules shown here shouldn't cause anything to appear "expired". Everything should work OK, the way I see it.  The statement that "we are no longer able to because client access has expired" is confusing to me, if these are the rules.

Comment: These rules will not trigger that message. There's nothing in there to determine the "in 3 day(s)" part from. So it's very likely the message is from another project/database, or was sent before the rules were changes in this database.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. The question that you referred me to does not answer my question which is why I asked a new one, as I did not have the date in my rules. I am aware that there is nothing that should have triggered that message and yet I got it and can no longer write to my database so I was wondering if there are any other ways to change my rules to allow read/write access or if this is the simplest way?