# Firebase Test Period is done

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hello i'm using firebase for my project with flutter, looks like the test period is done, but i still have some work to do, how to extend the period ? that's my rules on realtime database looks like :

```
{
  "rules": {
    
      
    
    ".read": "now < 1605567610000",  // 2020-11-17
   
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: just change this value 1605567610000 to whatever you want giving you more time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email: \[Firebase\] Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in X day(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869759/email-firebase-client-access-to-your-cloud-firestore-database-expiring-in-x-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 1605567610000 is a measurement of a point in time in milliseconds since unix epoch.  Your rules are saying that reads against the entire database are not allowed after that point in time.  You can simply increase that number to a point in time in the future when you would like read access to expire.  Use a tool like [this](https://currentmillis.com/) to come up with a new number.